# Layout below not properly working in Relativelayout

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

First of all please check this xml code :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/adass"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_channel"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/selector_add" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lnmr"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_Channel_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="My Channel"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_menu" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_Category_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="Category Name"
                android:textColor="@color/gray" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/img_channel"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/add_channel_logo_height"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/add_channel_logo_height"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/add_channel_placeholder"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/adass"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/img_channel"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@color/light_gray" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the output http://prntscr.com/d8ccq7

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure replace @id/adass with @+id/adass and try?

Comment: @Raghavendra I tried both way

Comment: clarify your question!!

Answer (score 0):

referencing a layout should be done as `android:layout_below="@+id/your_layout_id"` everywhere in your code,make sure u use @+id rather then @id

```
 <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/adass"
    android:background="@color/light_gray" />
```

try if this helps, if it does you can add margin and left alignments later to it

Comment: I tried both with @+id and @id in view, but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue and found out that the order of toLeftOf/toRightOf depends on the order of children in the layout xml. As an example when initialising an id, you have to use a "+" as in @+id/something before you can relate to the view as @id/something further down. I hope that makes sense. I believe if you change your layout to:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/adass"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/selector_add" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnmr"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_Channel_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="My Channel"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_menu" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_Category_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Category Name"
            android:textColor="@color/gray" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/img_channel"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/add_channel_logo_height"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/add_channel_logo_height"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/add_channel_placeholder"
    app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/adass" !!!!
/>
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/adass"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/img_channel"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@color/light_gray" />
```

This should work. :)

Answer (score 0):

add this line

```
 <view ....
android:layout_below="@id/adass"/>
```

Comment: This is not the solution dear!

Comment: <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/adass"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/img_channel"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

Comment: what is your expected result

Comment: I can use your code and change only few places,can you please show me the expected output(screen shot)

Comment: I want to show this view below linearlayout but it is showing in centervertical. Please check http://prntscr.com/d8ccq7

This is unexpected behaviour

Comment: Just like whatsApp did in home screen i want to show underline and with left of image

Comment: please check this - this is horizontal view ,http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1847564/d2549a4a0f05a49c2df1724f48ed0e3a

Comment: Yes I understand your problem,

Comment: i cannot have to share code so i send screen shot check it,http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1847621/74144dfed04d8124d1acf82e0ffc787c